# How to switch Libary window's tab in Xcode 11 by shortcuts?

Tags: xcode, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, xcode11

I am a big fan of Xcode and used a lot of Xcode shortcuts, and I love the Library window, which has a shortcut to bring it out, `cmd` + `L`.
But I can't find a way to switch the tab in the Xcode, place help me out. This thing becomes handy when developing SwiftUI project.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (`Ctrl` + `Tab`) and (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Tab`) to navigate forward and back on Library or use Window menu as well:

[image]