# What are the keyboard shortcuts for switching between different tab types in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

*I searched for this recently and the current set of questions and answers on stack overflow did have the answers but they were hard to find and so I felt they could be consolidated. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491023/what-is-the-way-to-quick-switch-between-tabs-in-xcode-4) is just about "window" tabs introduced in xcode 4, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64848710/shortcut-for-switching-between-tabs-in-xcode-now) is ambiguous, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65305116/how-to-switch-libary-windows-tab-in-xcode-11-by-shortcuts) just seems to be about the library window.*

There are now two types of tab in Xcode, "main" tabs along the top of the window and "sub" tabs within the editor areas within the window. What are the default keyboard shortcuts for switching / changing between them?

Answer (score 1):

### Xcode 11, 12, 13+

The "main" tabs (which were just normal tabs in previous versions of Xcode) are called "window" tabs, and the new in-editor area "sub" tabs are just "tabs".

| Action | Shortcut |
| --- | --- |
| **Go one window tab right:** | `Ctrl + Tab` |
| **Go one window tab left** | `Ctrl + Shift + Tab` |
| **Go one navigator tab right** | `Cmd + }` or (`Command + Shift + ]`) |
| **Go one navigator tab left** | `Cmd + {` or (`Command + Shift + [`) |

The menu commands for switching window tabs can be found in the **Window** menu, and those for navigator tabs in the **Navigate** menu.

### Older Xcodes

There were just plain old tabs like Safari / Finder.

| Action | Shortcut |
| --- | --- |
| **Go one editor tab right** | `Cmd + }` or (`Command + Shift + ]`) |
| **Go one editor tab left** | `Cmd + {` or (`Command + Shift + [`) |